Is LDAP (over LDAPS) mandatory to join a Windows client into an Active Directory?
We are building a migration factory for a bigger on-premises to GCP cloud migration. For that we have a VM platform with Compute Engine VMs. Currently the DC is located on-premises and the VMs are joind into the AD over LDAP. Is there a way to use LDAPs over LDAP or is there a technical need specified by windows implementation?
I want to know if there is a way to join a client into the domain in a completely secure way.


are joind into the AD over LDAP

They are joined into AD over LDAP using Kerberos transport security. While Kerberos has its own issues, it is not the same as plain LDAP – it should provide a sufficient level of security assuming a properly managed domain (i.e. no RC4-only user or service accounts involved).
After you enter the AD admin password to get a Kerberos ticket, the protocol authenticates both the client and the LDAP server at the same time (without the need for a TLS certificate), and provides a session key that Windows will use for transport encryption (usually AES).
It does somewhat rest on the admin password being infeasible to bruteforce, though, so you could instead do an "offline" join using the djoin tool – prepare the machine account locally, upload the file to VM, provision it.
Once the machine is joined, it'll do the same thing to access LDAP using Kerberos with its machine account (which always has a stronger password).
Still, that being said, LDAP is the least of your worries – it's not the only protocol involved in AD membership, both during join and during normal operation after join. Your VMs will also be accessing SMB to download GPOs (so hopefully you have SMBv3 encryption set to mandatory on your DCs), they'll be doing CLDAP pings (hope you have rate limiting for those), they'll be accessing various RPC services (those also use Kerberos), and they'll be doing this from the same GCP IP address pool as millions of other machines that your DCs are now exposed to...
So, even Kerberos aside, it would not be enough to just enable TLS for the DC services – the only way to do this actually securely is to set up a VPN between GCP and your local network, e.g. an IPsec tunnel, and to disallow all external access to your DCs.

Yep, LDAP is pretty much for the DC locator part - as you mention, the main stuff is Kerberos, SMB and RPC. I totally endorse the concept of needing a secure tunnel between external clients and on-prem DCs. This article outlines the required ports for the services mentioned above https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/windows-server/active-directory/active-directory-domain-join-troubleshooting-guidance

@LeeM: No, not only for the DC locator – LDAP is also how machine accounts are created, how GPO lists are obtained, etc. Sure, there is RPC for some of that (most of it predating AD), but LDAP is the main entry point.

Oh sure, it's doing an LDAP operation to do the add-object, didn't mean to imply otherwise
